# Embedded PDF Issue in Edge Browser

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, iframe, browser, microsoft-edge

When using the Microsoft Edge browser, by default when you open a PDF it will open the PDF in a new tab using the built-in PDF viewer. To avoid this, you can adjust the browser's settings: Toggle on the "Always open PDF files externally" option. This works great. However, it presents a separate issue. Our internal applications use embedded PDFs in iframes. When the external toggle is set to on, these PDFs will not show in the iframes. This doesn't happen in Chrome. Has anyone else experienced this and know a work around?

I've tried removing the `type="application/pdf"` from the iframe tag to no avail. I can't find anything else online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an expected result because you have enabled the option **Always open PDF files externally**.

So MS Edge browser is giving you an option to download the PDF file and open it using the desired app.

[image]

You said this doesn't happen in Chrome browser.

If you enabled the **Download PDF files instead of automatically opening them in Chrome** option then you will notice the same result in the Chrome browser.

[image]

Output in the Chrome browser:

[image]

If you click on the Open button then it will download the PDF file.

I did not get any solution or a workaround for this issue.

If you think that there should be an option to load the file in an iframe if **Always open PDF files externally** option is enabled then I suggest you click on the **Send Feedback** button in the MS Edge browser and try to provide your feedback about it to the Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

I posted feedback suggesting that an exclusion/inclusion list be in included but the simplest way would be to treat the frame as part of the session. But this is not Microsoft it is the Chrome projects issue.